# Pagination based on numbers or date?

Tags: seo, google, pagination

In a blog you'll have many many many posts.

Every single post has a page.

I did read that you shouldn't do an archive based on date but based on topic, which makes sense:
https://yoast.com/archive-seo/

When doing a archive based on topic how should you do pagination?

Do pagination based on date:

```
< prev week/month - next week/month >
```

Or do pagination based on numbers:

```
1, [2], 3, 4, 5
```

(the yoast dot com website does pagination base on numbers)

When doing pagination based on numbers wouldn't it be bad that when a new post is added every page in your archive changes? (everything shifts down one position). This isn't the case with date based pagination.

Comment: Google isn't going to reward you any more using months or numbers... Use whatever you consider to offer a better UX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yoast is recommending to group content based on topics rather than dates. They basically are saying, in your sidebar navigation provide links to content related to each topic. Well, I believe that will be a good advise for most bloggers.

Pagination Using the link property rel=“prev” and rel=“next” is to let google know that your content is related to each other and follows a logical sequence. For instance, if you are talking about aircrafts, you can have a page talking about the history of airplanes rel=“next”, another page about evolution of aerodynamics, rel=“next”, another page about comercial airlines, and so on.

What matters here is the markup you use, not what you use to create the links: numbers, Roman numerals, months, years.

However, the link properties will be useful and well implemented if you content is ordered in a logical sequence like [explained here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663744?hl=en) . If not, Do not use it, just create the links without the rel=“prev” and rel=“next” properties.

Remember you can always offer different navigation options to your users, is really is up to you. If your users are happy, everybody is happy. Create the categories by taxonomy or topics like Yoast recommendation and link them together the way you think is optimal for your users, create next month, previous month and a sidebar navigation with them.

Comment: Cheers @titico for the detailed reply! On a side note: it's good to hear that what user want has become more important.